# How do select data from just 7 days back

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select data from just 7 days back?

Let's say if it's January 7th today : I only want to fetch data from January 1st.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help] so you can learn the guidelines of the site. I'd also recommend reading some tutorials and learning about SQL! There is some great information out there that can help you learn this and MUCH more about SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
where DateCol between DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() ) and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about times, and `datecol` is never in the future, then:

```
where datecol > convert(date, dateadd(day, -7, getdate())
```